# Why does lastValueFrom says there are no elements when getValue gives me data?

Tags: rxjs, jestjs

I have some code like this in a test:

```js
console.log(workingStore$.getValue());

await lastValueFrom(workingStore$);
```

The `console.log` returns a value, yet my `lastValueFrom` call makes an error of  `EmptyError: no elements in sequence`. Not sure how it's possible to receive values but be told I have no elements.

Comment: What is `workingStore$`? Is it a Subject?

Answer (score 0):

This test failed cause some order of operations changed. But basically I needed to do this:

```js
const promise = lastValueFrom(workingStore$);

// logic that populates workingStore$

await promise;
```

Then things worked.